Is there a way to generate invokedynamic bytecode using BCEL?
I want to generate invokedynamic bytecode using BCEL library.
Using BCEL I want to generate a class file which calls a bootstrap method using invokedynamic opcode. I can see BCEL has INVOKEDYNAMIC instruction, but I am not sure how to use that with methodhandle.
Bootstrap Class looks like this:
import java.lang.invoke.*;

public class MyBootstrap {
    public static CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup caller, String name, MethodType type) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        // Find the target method dynamically
        MethodHandle target = caller.findVirtual(MyDynamicClass.class, name, type);

        // Return a CallSite with the MethodHandle
        return new ConstantCallSite(target);
    }
}

MyDynamicClass :
public class MyDynamicClass {
    public void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + "!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a ClassGen to generate the class
        ClassGen classGen = new ClassGen("GeneratedInvoker", "java.lang.Object", "GeneratedInvoker.java", Const.ACC_PUBLIC | Const.ACC_SUPER, null);

        // Create the constructor method
        InstructionList il = new InstructionList();
        MethodGen constructor = new MethodGen(Const.ACC_PUBLIC, Type.VOID, new Type[]{}, new String[]{}, "<init>", "GeneratedInvoker", il, classGen.getConstantPool());

        // Call super() in constructor
        il.append(InstructionFactory.createLoad(Type.OBJECT, 0));
        il.append(new INVOKESPECIAL(classGen.getConstantPool().addMethodref("java.lang.Object", "<init>", "()V")));
        il.append(InstructionFactory.createReturn(Type.VOID));

        // Add the constructor method to the class
        constructor.setMaxStack(1);
        classGen.addMethod(constructor.getMethod());
        il.dispose();

        // Create the main method: public static void main(String[] args)
        il = new InstructionList();
        MethodGen mainMethod = new MethodGen(Const.ACC_PUBLIC | Const.ACC_STATIC, Type.VOID, new Type[]{new ArrayType(Type.STRING, 1)}, new String[]{"args"}, "main", "GeneratedInvoker", il, classGen.getConstantPool());

        // Create an instance of MyDynamicClass
        il.append(new NEW(classGen.getConstantPool().addClass("MyDynamicClass")));
        il.append(InstructionFactory.createDup(1));
        il.append(new INVOKESPECIAL(classGen.getConstantPool().addMethodref("MyDynamicClass", "<init>", "()V")));

        // Push the argument for the sayHello method
        il.append(new PUSH(classGen.getConstantPool(), "world"));
        
// Add the ConstantMethodRef object to the constant pool
        int bootstrapMethodRefIndex = classGen.getConstantPool().addMethodref("MyBootstrap","bootstrap","(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;");
        
        // Add invokedynamic instruction
        ConstantMethodHandle methodHandle = new ConstantMethodHandle(
                Constants.INVOKESTATIC,
                bootstrapMethodRefIndex
        );
        // dont know how to use this methodHandle
        INVOKEDYNAMIC invokedynamic = new INVOKEDYNAMIC(bootstrapMethodRefIndex);

        il.append(invokedynamic);

        // Return from the main method
        il.append(InstructionFactory.createReturn(Type.VOID));

        // Add the main method to the class
        mainMethod.setMaxStack(3);
        classGen.addMethod(mainMethod.getMethod());
        il.dispose();

        // Write the generated class to a file
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("GeneratedInvoker.class")) {
            classGen.getJavaClass().dump(fos);
        }

        System.out.println("GeneratedInvoker.class has been created!");
    }

but this didn't work and when I try to run i got following Error:
Unable to initialize main class GeneratedInvoker Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 13 in method GeneratedInvoker.main(\[Ljava/lang/String;)V

Following is the bytecode generated:
public class GeneratedInvoker
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: (0x0021) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #4                          // GeneratedInvoker
  super_class: #6                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 2, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               SourceFile
   #2 = Utf8               GeneratedInvoker.java
   #3 = Utf8               GeneratedInvoker
   #4 = Class              #3             // GeneratedInvoker
   #5 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #6 = Class              #5             // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               ()V
   #9 = NameAndType        #7:#8          // "<init>":()V
  #10 = Methodref          #6.#9          // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #11 = Utf8               this
  #12 = Utf8               LGeneratedInvoker;
  #13 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #14 = Utf8               Code
  #15 = Utf8               MyDynamicClass
  #16 = Class              #15            // MyDynamicClass
  #17 = Methodref          #16.#9         // MyDynamicClass."<init>":()V
  #18 = Utf8               world
  #19 = String             #18            // world
  #20 = Utf8               bootstrap
  #21 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #22 = NameAndType        #20:#21        // bootstrap:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #23 = Utf8               MyBootstrap
  #24 = Class              #23            // MyBootstrap
  #25 = Methodref          #24.#22        // MyBootstrap.bootstrap:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
  #26 = Utf8               main
  #27 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #28 = Utf8               args
  #29 = Utf8               [Ljava/lang/String;
{
  public GeneratedInvoker();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LGeneratedInvoker;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #16                 // class MyDynamicClass
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #17                 // Method MyDynamicClass."<init>":()V
         7: ldc           #19                 // String world
         9: invokedynamic #25,  0             // Method MyBootstrap.bootstrap:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
        14: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      13     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
}
SourceFile: "GeneratedInvoker.java"


There’s definitely something missing. An invokedynamic instruction does not only need a bootstrap method but also a name and type. While the semantics of the name is up to you, it can’t work without specifying what values the instruction is supposed to consume and what type the result will be. I never tried that with BCEL. I use the ASM library which I know can generate working invokedynamic instructions.

True, I have tried with ASM and I am able to generate working invokedynamic instruction but not with BCEL.
